# Exclude multiple paths from htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a new function with the hope of achieving breadcrumbs and a better URL structure.

Before this I had the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-z0-9,&-]+)/?$ ?action=viewArticleName&page_identifier=$1 [L,NC,QSA,B]
```

This meant;

```
www.example.com/pages/contact
```

returned an article from the DB. Now I wanted to change this so my urls look like

```
www.example.com/categoryname/pagename
```

so my working rewrite rule for this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /?action=viewCategoryName&categoryName=$1&page_identifier=$2 [L]
```

The problem is this RewriteRule is causing any images being included from /images to load an included template for the article.

I can think of three possible solutions, but not actual code:

1) Could I create an array of the category names? I could then somehow make the RewriteRule apply to only these names.

2)Create a class to contain some global settings. In this have some php that defines or sets the image path. All i can think of is;

```
define( "IMAGE_PATH", "//example.com/images" );
```

3)Add something to the Htacces file to exclude certain paths from the rule.

I know MVC or similar would achieve much better results. This is about my learning, please tell me if ive dug myself into a hole here!

Many Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **skip all existing files and directories** from this rewrite like this to prevent all images getting affected with this new rule:

```
# skip all existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# skip all existing directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?action=viewCategoryName&categoryName=$1&page_identifier=$2 [L,QSA,B]
```

NB, added 'B' to flags, this escapes non-alphanumeric characters such as '&'.

Comment: thats worked perfectly! Would you mind explaining what part of the code is making it skip all existing files/directories?

Comment: I added some comments in my answer. Basically `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means if it is not a file and `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means if request is not for a directory.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks for elaborating will mark your comment up